# AWS S3 bucket stopped working after upgrading EC2 from t2.micro to t2.nano

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mount

On AWS I have migrated an EC2 instance from a t2.micro (free) to a t2.nano to get more CPU cycles. At that point, I changed nothing in the AWS EC2 console except the instance type. It started up and is faster, but I'm having trouble with my s3fs buckets staying mounted.

I need the S3 buckets to mount at startup reliably and to stay mounted.

Environment:

```
# uname --all
Linux localhost 5.15.0-1033-aws #37~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 11:39:30 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# s3fs --version
Amazon Simple Storage Service File System V1.86 (commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
```

More Details:

I have two s3 buckets that have had problems auto mounting on boot up (/etc/fstab) from the beginning of setting up this EC2 instance. As a work around, I created a remount.sh script to mount them which worked decently well if I ran it manually several times after a reboot.

That script is here:

```
# cat remount.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Before remount"
mount -l | grep s3fs

echo "Unmounting....."
umount /mnt/ftpusers
umount /mnt/random

echo "Mounting....."
s3fs -f -d s3-bucket-1 /mnt/ftpusers -o passwd_file=/root/.passwd-s3fs -o url=https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -o use_path_request_style -o allow_other -o nonempty >> /var/log/s3fs.log &
s3fs -f -d s3-bucket-2 /mnt/random -o passwd_file=/root/.passwd-s3fs -o url=https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -o use_path_request_style -o allow_other -o nonempty >> /var/log/s3fs.log &

echo "After remount"
#Duplicate lines because it takes a sec sometimes.
mount -l | grep s3fs
mount -l | grep s3fs
```

Prior to running the script with nothing mounted: (Are my file permissions right?)

```
# ls -la /mnt
total 9
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 13  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Apr  2 19:27 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 ftpusers
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 random
```

After trying some file operations on the ftpusers subfolders and files, I get some errors (see below) and this is what I see in the /mnt/ directory. If I were to do the same with the /mnt/random/ folder, it crashes the mount too.

```
# ls -la /mnt
ls: cannot access '/mnt/ftpusers': Transport endpoint is not connected
total 9
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 13  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Apr  2 19:27 ..
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? ftpusers
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 random
```

After running the script:

```
# ~/lpr-scripts/remount.sh
Before remount
s3fs on /mnt/ftpusers type fuse.s3fs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
s3fs on /mnt/random type fuse.s3fs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
Unmounting.....
Mounting.....
After remount
s3fs on /mnt/ftpusers type fuse.s3fs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
s3fs on /mnt/random type fuse.s3fs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

I am getting a lot of these errors

```
Software caused connection abort
find: Failed to restore initial working directory: Transport endpoint is not connected
0
find: ‘./xxxxxxx’: Transport endpoint is not connected
find: Failed to restore initial working directory: /mnt/ftpusers: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

In /var/log/s3fs I see this happening when I run 'remount.sh':

```
# cat /var/log/s3fs.log
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [INF]
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4400): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40755)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3493): init v1.86(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3828): check services.
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2431): HTTP response code 400, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>Y69Q62MK4A6VA0QC</RequestId><HostId>4ReUR9oaB7EUBWRcZWdOlcsC6oX1HcpfcC9OJaMN2d16kfi1Yg3mH/EwV8T86rg4iN8Y6i49C30=</HostId></Error>
[ERR] curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3439): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>Y69Q62MK4A6VA0QC</RequestId><HostId>4ReUR9oaB7EUBWRcZWdOlcsC6oX1HcpfcC9OJaMN2d16kfi1Yg3mH/EwV8T86rg4iN8Y6i49C30=</HostId></Error>
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3862): Failed to connect region 'us-east-1'(default), so retry to connect region 'us-east-2'.
[INF] curl.cpp:ReturnHandler(318): Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2416): HTTP response code 200
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_getattr(876): [path=/]
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_destroy(3546): destroy
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [INF]
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4400): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40755)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3493): init v1.86(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3828): check services.
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2431): HTTP response code 400, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>Y69H328JJFKYMRRZ</RequestId><HostId>+laHSpHkzT5+iuuc15w1eZB9yxdTuzLerhvioM01hKf8lG6GoYaNL788NADH6HIHGuhtNf9S9JY=</HostId></Error>
[ERR] curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3439): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>Y69H328JJFKYMRRZ</RequestId><HostId>+laHSpHkzT5+iuuc15w1eZB9yxdTuzLerhvioM01hKf8lG6GoYaNL788NADH6HIHGuhtNf9S9JY=</HostId></Error>
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3862): Failed to connect region 'us-east-1'(default), so retry to connect region 'us-east-2'.
[INF] curl.cpp:ReturnHandler(318): Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2416): HTTP response code 200
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_getattr(876): [path=/]
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_destroy(3546): destroy
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [INF]
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4400): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40755)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3493): init v1.86(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3828): check services.
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2431): HTTP response code 400, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>FXAPN5DG1J0A2B2P</RequestId><HostId>JaaZCGoE40faMlIygOJpgk3Lsh9rgep3OIg1yMcWXiFKQDUDrz/WCM5NpA6dcg5ipjibdfHPOLQ=</HostId></Error>
[ERR] curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3439): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>FXAPN5DG1J0A2B2P</RequestId><HostId>JaaZCGoE40faMlIygOJpgk3Lsh9rgep3OIg1yMcWXiFKQDUDrz/WCM5NpA6dcg5ipjibdfHPOLQ=</HostId></Error>
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3862): Failed to connect region 'us-east-1'(default), so retry to connect region 'us-east-2'.
[INF] curl.cpp:ReturnHandler(318): Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-1/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2416): HTTP response code 200
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_getattr(876): [path=/]
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_destroy(3546): destroy
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [INF]
[INF]     s3fs.cpp:set_mountpoint_attribute(4400): PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40755)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_init(3493): init v1.86(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3828): check services.
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[ERR] curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2431): HTTP response code 400, returning EIO. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>FXAZD71YBT9H4RGE</RequestId><HostId>A8MaZ/GWhiDrfHTrrCK7jCbzobrgi7josatwwSlTI57XOPj5yGoD6uAqsdDgOowxgrO33ixymHk=</HostId></Error>
[ERR] curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3439): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationHeaderMalformed</Code><Message>The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2'</Message><Region>us-east-2</Region><RequestId>FXAZD71YBT9H4RGE</RequestId><HostId>A8MaZ/GWhiDrfHTrrCK7jCbzobrgi7josatwwSlTI57XOPj5yGoD6uAqsdDgOowxgrO33ixymHk=</HostId></Error>
[CRT] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3862): Failed to connect region 'us-east-1'(default), so retry to connect region 'us-east-2'.
[INF] curl.cpp:ReturnHandler(318): Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
[INF]       curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3413): check a bucket.
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4703): URL is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:prepare_url(4736): URL changed is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/s3-bucket-2/
[INF]       curl.cpp:insertV4Headers(2753): computing signature [GET] [/] [] []
[INF]       curl.cpp:url_to_host(99): url is https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
[INF]       curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2416): HTTP response code 200
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_getattr(876): [path=/]
[INF] s3fs.cpp:s3fs_destroy(3546): destroy
```

I see the errors with the wrong region. So I check this:

```
# cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = us-east-2
output = text
```

By the way, I'm running this manually as root while I am unsure what user the /etc/fstab is running as at boot up.

Another strange issue is that the `~root/.passwd-s3fs` file does not match the `~root/.aws.credentials` file, but it works all day, everyday on a different EC2 instance. At this point, I am uncertain which S3 credentials are correct. This could be my problem, but I've changed both credentials (`~root/.passwd-s3fs` and `~root/.aws/credentials`) to match and it seems to make it unable to connect at all. I'm pretty confused about this point here. Does one override the other? When are they used at all? (only on initial mount, or for every file read/write, etc?)

Where are the AWS s3fs credentials and config stored for `/etc/fstab` on startup?

Thanks in advance for looking at this with me.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking Programming Q&A. Your question is likely to be closed. You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Go back to t2.micro and check if it works. If it works, than it means that t2.nano is too small.

Comment: I had this auto mount problem when it was a t2.micro.   t2.micro is the smallest, right?  t2.micro is the free tier.  It's why I upgraded to the t2.nano.

Comment: I had this question on serverfault and got no traction at all.  So I deleted it and brought it over here.